# How do I recover tab cycling in Terminal.app?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal.app

Today I've noticed that Cmd+} has stopped working for me in Snow Leopard's Terminal.app as a shortcut to cycle to the next tab. Cmd+{ still works. I've gone to the Preferences->keyboard shortcuts and when I try to create a new shortcut pressing Cmd+} I get Cmd+alt+Ç in the window. I get Cmd+alt+´ when pressing Cmd+{ (I'm on a Spanish macbook pro).

I've also noticed that I cannot create a custom shortcut for Terminal.app, because it is not in the list of applications I can create shortcuts for, and neither can I add it to the list.

How can I debug what is "eating" the cycle right tab shortcut key? I've got sizzling keys plugin, keyboard remapper (for the esc/capslock key) but I've tried disabling them and still didn't recover the terminal shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not a foolproof method, search for recent global keyboard shortcuts to see if something is *eating* the key combination. Looking at the shortcuts for universal access, looks like the Cmd+alt+Ç combo is assigned to "Activate/desactivate image smoothing", which probably got assigned when enabling "Activate access for help devices" under Universal access.